# Splitting string into several different strings

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am getting the source code from a site and putting the code into a string, the will look like this:

```
501252,110,34496
331550,30,14114
403186,1,18
325033,31,15750
460287,14,2384
286659,11,1366
419439,1,67
678464,1,0
505044,1,70
522192,1,75
454391,1,0
504858,1,20
505396,1,40
469927,1,0
336670,2,155
392887,5,437
403568,1,0
488324,1,0
524031,1,0
429226,1,0
389668,1,0
383021,1,0
384599,1,0
363131,1,0
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
```

I want to split each number, and save them in there own strings, how could i go about this?

current code: (if it is any help?)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class dfgdfg {

    static String username;
    static JTextField USERNAME = new JTextField();
    static String pooo;
    static JPanel panel;
    static JFrame jframe;
    static JButton button;
    static String line;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
GUI();
    }

    public static void getSource() {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;

        try {
            url = new URL(
                    "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player="+username);
            is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
        }
    public static void GUI() {
        jframe = new JFrame("HighscoreLookup");
        panel = new JPanel();
        USERNAME = new JTextField("Enter Username");
        button = new JButton("START");

        jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.add(panel);

        panel.add(USERNAME);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        button.setVisible(true);
        USERNAME.setSize(100,50);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                username = USERNAME.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(username);
                getSource();

            }
        });   
        jframe.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: just call a split(",") on each string... and check the API  before asking :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, i ment, i need each of the numbers into their own strings. Edited the question.

Comment: @willbaker give an example of output that you want

Comment: Well, that is the single string of the code i get, i want each one of the number to have there own string, 501252, and so on, would have their own string.

Answer (score 1):

Read each line from your file with a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and use [String.split(",")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on each line. Very useful utility.

`String.split` will break your string into a 1D array using the provided regex statement. Here you'll just be breaking each line by each comma.

Edit:

Based on your comment this will *still* work for you.

Given input `"501252,110,34496"` output would be `"501252", "110", "34496"`

Run this code to see what I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String input = "501252,110,34496";
    String output = input.split(",");
    String[] outputContainsThis = new String[]{"501252", "110", "34496"};
}
```

Does this suffice?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i ment, i need each of the numbers into their own strings. Edited the question.

Comment: I'm confused... split should still work for you. Split does exactly what you want. I've edited my answer. Please clarify what you need and I'll happily provide.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split method of the string class:

```
"data1,data2".Split(',');
//will return an array containing 2strings: data1 then data2
```

You can Split the whole thing with \n then split each line with ,
Or read it line by line with a scanner or some buffered reader.

Answer (score 0):

```java
"501252,110,34496".split(",") // => ["501252", "110", "34496"]
```

Comment: Ok i can use a StringTokenizer, but the code below wont work because it wont split the commas, only the spaces, could anyone tell me how to make it split the commas aswell? Thanks
    
 `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("line");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `char[] cArray = mystring.toCharArray();`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. The easiest is to use split:

```
String inputString = "line 1\nline 2\n";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String[] lines = inputString.split("\\n");

for(String line : lines)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The way I would do it is roughly like this, because it allows easy error handling, character escaping, and other processing:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
{
    char next = inputString.charAt(i);

    if(next == '\\')
    {
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    if(next == '\n')
    {
        lines.add(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        continue;
    }

    sb.append(next);
}

if(sb.length() > 0)
{
    lines.add(sb.toString());
}

for(String line : lines)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

UPDATE: the question was changed from lines to fields. You can still use split, but be wary of special characters, new line characters, etc. The right way to handle this type of input would be to use a CSV parser to process the input (see RFC 4180: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Comment: Ok i can use a StringTokenizer, but the code below wont work because it wont split the commas, only the spaces, could anyone tell me how to make it split the commas aswell? Thanks    'StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("line");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }'